# Error running Scala tests in Intelli-J

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm having some problems getting my Scala tests running via the Intelli-J Run/Debug configuration. The tests are working if I run them directly in the SBT console.

My configuration looks like this:

[image]

I'm getting this error in the Run console panel:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -r has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpose in the near future. Please change all uses of -r to -C.
at org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.checkArgsForValidity(ArgsParser.scala:41)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:857)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:141)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I've checked my plugins are all up-to-date. Do I need to use a particular version of Scala? Or is there some additional setup I'm missing?

Comment: It may be worthwhile to re-import your project, i.e. delete the existing IDEA project info, and then importing it again.

Comment: ^ re-importing does no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been a problem with the Scala plugin under Intelli-J 13.

I fixed this by upgrading to Intelli-J 2016.3, which I presume has been changed to pass the newer `-C` switch to ScalaTestRunner.

*@JasonF pointed out in his comment below that a project dependency can also cause a problem with the scalatest plugin (this was the case for him). It's worth attempting to run the tests of a fresh sample Scala project to test for this scenario before upgrading the IDE.*

Comment: @JasonF are you getting the exact error I was seeing? In the console panel: " `-r has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported` "

Comment: Yes, co-workers and I are seeing the exact same issue in Intellij. In the past I was able to downgrade my plugin, but that's no longer working. What we might do is just fork the plugin code & manually install from disk to fix this behavior.

Comment: Strange. It just worked for me after I upgraded to 2016.3. I don't think downgrading the Intellij plugin would help here as older ScalaTestRunner versions always called the deprecated -r switch... you need the most recent ScalaTest library

Comment: It turned out to be a dependency related / project specific issue -- i was able to confirm this by switching to another project & suddenly I was able to run tests (and that's still using the older version of scalatest). The only difference is that we now load an old version of embedded kafka (0.8) earlier now. For whatever reason, the scalatest runner thinks we are running an older version than we really are, so it replaces "-C" with "-r" and this error triggers.

Comment: @JasonF glad to hear you got things working, interesting to know that a project dependency could have caused this side effect. I'll amend my answer to include your findings in case others have the same issue.

Comment: I've been pulled into other projects so I haven't had time to go back & fix this. Looking at the Git diffs, its still my intuition that this is a dependency issue... It should be impossible, but it appears like the scala test runner is somehow using a different dependency tree than Maven (the maven scala test plugin is pretty old so maybe its the issue). I'll post an update once I know more.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me posted @JasonF; very happy to revise my answer or vote/accept your own one if you later stumble on a common cause. Upgrading is an expensive risk if it doesn't fix the problem for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has this problem even with newer version of IntelliJ, here is how I went about figuring out where the issue was. I pulled in the scalatest dependency at the top of the pom for the module I was trying to run tests in. Then an individual test would run without this error. I moved the dependency down the pom until the problem recurred to figure out which dependency was causing the problem. Then I found that the dependency had some really old dependencies including an older version of scalatest that weren't showing up in my dependency tree. Also, this jar dependency had scalatest as a dependency not marked with scope test.